# "use strict" causes undefined error

Tags: javascript, jslint, use-strict

I am defining the following function in my JavaScript:

```
function _snr(id) {
    "use strict";
    this.e = "something";
}
```

I ran my code through JSLint and it suggested that I add "use strict" to the function.

When I do `e` now throws and undefined error. From some initial investigation it looks as though `this` which used to refer to `_snr` is no longer defined.

I have read about "use strict" and discovered that it is used to prevent unsafe practices. Could some one explain what was unsafe about this? What "use strict" is actually doing and how I can fix my code?

Comment: What makes you think `this` would refer to `_snr`? The value of `this` depends on how you invoke the function. If you're doing `_snr(123)`, then `this` will be the global object, except in strict mode, where it will be `undefined`.

Comment: I suppose it is assuming you are accessing the global with `this`, which is a no-no to JSLint. Of course, if you are using `new _snr`, this is not true.

Comment: Strict mode is virtually useless on the web at present, turn off whatever option will stop JSLint saying that. If code is written to use strict mode features, it will fail in browsers that don't implement it. If it doesn't take advantage of strict mode, then it's pointless (and possibly harmful, as you've discovered) including it.

Comment: @user1689607 i'm a noob to js so forgive me if I am wrong, but when I look a `this` in the browser inspector it refers to `snr`, am I missing something?

Comment: @Asad, so how would I access global? Or should I not be doing this at all?

Comment: @ferics2: `this` in JavaScript is dynamic. Its value is dependant on how you invoke the function. It's possible that it could refer to the `snr` function, but it would be very unlikely. More likely it refers to the global (window) object, especially if you're now getting `undefined` as a `this` value.

Comment: Can you post the code which calls `_snr`? I created a jdFiddle and it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/z6MLX/

Comment: @Asad: `_snr.call(_snr)` Now `this` refers to the function. Or like this: `_snr.fn = _snr; _snr.fn()`. A recursive call will never itself make `this` refer to the function.

Comment: @RobG I wouldn't say that anything `"use strict";` inherently breaks backwards compatibility. I would say that there are ESHarmony/ESNext features (which don't require `"use strict";` statements) which ***can*** break incompatible browsers. It doesn't do much right now, except throw the kinds of errors you can expect to be thrown in new browsers, if you stick to ES3-syntax, but with ES6 (/5-strict) - incompatible techniques, like `this` pointing at nothing or using `with` statements.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If a function is called without setting its `this`, in non–strict mode its `this` will be set to reference the global (window in a browser) object. In strict mode, it wil remain undefined.

If your function is called as `_snr(...)` then its `this` is not set, so in non–strict mode `this` will be set to the global object so `this.e = ...` references (or creates due to the assignment) a global `e` property.

However, in strict mode `this` will be undefined, and trying to access a property of undefined throws an error.

It's explained in [ECMA-262 §10.4.3 Entering Function Code](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3).

#### Edit

If you wish to access the global object from inside a function in a manner that is consistent with both strict and non–strict mode, you can use something like:

```
var _snr = (function(global) {
    return function (id) {
        global.e = "something";
    };
}(this));
```

In non-strict mode, you can do:

```
function _snr(id) {
    var global = (function(){return this;}());
    global.e = "something";
}
```

so that `global` within the function references the global object and you don't have to worry about how the function is called. But the second example won't work in strict mode.

#### Other answers:

> I have read about "use strict" and discovered that it is used to prevent unsafe practices. Could some one explain what was unsafe about this?

Absolutely nothing in this particular case.

However, in a more general case, it was considered a good idea to be able to execute code within a context that stopped it accessing the global object directly. The second example above shows how that can be done in non–strict code (i.e. how you can get direct access to the global object from inside a function context).

> What "use strict" is actually doing

It is stopping `this` being set to the global object if the call sets it to `undefined` or `null`. See above for the consequence of that.

> and how I can fix my code?

See above.

Oh, and finally, there is an informative summary of strict mode in [ECMA-262 Annex C The Strict Mode of ECMAScript](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-C).

Comment: @ferics2 it's just horrible practice, which has the potential to ruin everyone's day. Two examples: 1) creating a constructor function and calling it without `new` -- instead of returning an object, the constructor writes the object's values to global properties. 2) callbacks/functions inside of functions -- you think that `this` refers to an object, the outer-function's scope, or a DOM node... instead, it refers to `window`. And instead of the program spitting out an error that you screwed up, it just writes/overwrites/reads `window` properties and keeps going like everything's peachy.

Comment: @ferics2—it means you can prevent random code loaded by say XHR from accessing the global object and redefining your global variables. There are other ways around that, but tightening up on `this` is handy if you need it. Try [It’s time to start using JavaScript strict mode](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/03/13/its-time-to-start-using-javascript-strict-mode/) by Nicholas C. Zakas.